# Internet Explorer IE 8 overlay lines render issue on dropdown

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, rendering, html-rendering

I have an issue with menu dropdowns that use JQuery.  Using IE8, take a look at my menu just below the header.  Hover over 'Acrylic Awards', then 'Award Plaques', then 'Crystal Awards'.

http://www.blackacedesign.com/

Anyone know what causes this issue in IE8?  And how I can fix it?

Comment: Looks good in IE8 to me, not seeing any discrepancy from FF to IE8.

Comment: ok I see a slight difference when viewing in IE8 Compatability mode.  In IE8 Compatability mode the border between the menu items is transparent. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: No.  I am seeing lines that are "left behind" after the sub category has been hidden.  Almost as though they are impression marks from the border of the list items, during the jquery hide.  I see this sometimes when surfing other sites also.  I only see this in IE8.  FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari...etc.  all work fine.

Comment: I have an image of the issue I am seeing uploaded to my site, but I cannot post the image on here, because I am a new user.  Here is the link:

http://www.blackacedesign.com/ie8_render.jpg